# Change column format of DF, where some columns are dicts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

I'm new to pandas and I need help. Below I described my DF, which I need to change.

```
     id                               title  \
0   121852                 {'en': 'Hard Fork'}   
1   123209  {'en': 'Quarterly Public Meeting'}   
2   122436      {'en': 'Luxy NFT Marketplace'}   
3   122995          {'en': 'Poloniex Listing'}
4   123391       {'en': 'Staking 3.0 Release'}
5   123355           {'en': 'BitMart Listing'}
6   122819                 {'en': 'Amazy IGO'}
7   123470          {'en': 'YouTube Live AMA'}
8   123392                       {'en': 'AMA'}
9   123319             {'en': 'LBank Listing'}
10  123306            {'en': 'Community Call'}
11  123465         {'en': 'Digifinex Listing'}
12  123469       {'en': 'MEXC Global Listing'}
13  123512     {'en': 'Metarun & Fabwelt AMA'}
14  123460         {'en': 'Digifinex Listing'}
15  123489           {'en': 'BitMart Listing'}


                                                                                                   coins  \
0   [{'id': 'gxchain', 'coingecko_id': '', 'name': 'GXChain', 'rank': 442, 'symbol': 'GXC', 'fullname': 'GXChain (GXC)'}, {'id': 'rei-network', 'coingecko_id': '', 'name': 'REI Network', 'rank': 376, 'symbol': 'REI', 'fullname': 'REI Network (REI)'}]
1                                                                                                                                  [{'id': 'filecoin', 'coingecko_id': '', 'name': 'Filecoin', 'rank': 45, 'symbol': 'FIL', 'fullname': 'Filecoin (FIL)'}]
2                        [{'id': 'luxy', 'coingecko_id': '', 'name': 'Luxy', 'rank': 0, 'symbol': 'LUXY', 'fullname': 'Luxy (LUXY)'}, {'id': 'syscoin', 'coingecko_id': '', 'name': 'Syscoin', 'rank': 240, 'symbol': 'SYS', 'fullname': 'Syscoin (SYS)'}]
3                                                                                                                        [{'id': 'bitkub-coin', 'coingecko_id': '', 'name': 'Bitkub Coin', 'rank': 125, 'symbol': 'KUB', 'fullname': 'Bitkub Coin (KUB)'}]
4                                                                                                                                     [{'id': 'sidus', 'coingecko_id': '', 'name': 'Sidus', 'rank': 1231, 'symbol': 'SIDUS', 'fullname': 'Sidus (SIDUS)'}]
5                                                                                                                                      [{'id': 'solve', 'coingecko_id': '', 'name': 'SOLVE', 'rank': 693, 'symbol': 'SOLVE', 'fullname': 'SOLVE (SOLVE)'}]
6                                                                                                                 [{'id': 'seedify-fund', 'coingecko_id': '', 'name': 'Seedify.fund', 'rank': 389, 'symbol': 'SFUND', 'fullname': 'Seedify.fund (SFUND)'}]
7                                                                                                                [{'id': 'oasis-network', 'coingecko_id': '', 'name': 'Oasis Network', 'rank': 134, 'symbol': 'ROSE', 'fullname': 'Oasis Network (ROSE)'}]
8                                                                                                                                           [{'id': 'dydx', 'coingecko_id': '', 'name': 'dYdX', 'rank': 157, 'symbol': 'DYDX', 'fullname': 'dYdX (DYDX)'}]
9                                                                                                                                            [{'id': 'grove', 'coingecko_id': '', 'name': 'Grove', 'rank': 0, 'symbol': 'GVR', 'fullname': 'Grove (GVR)'}]
10                                                                                                [{'id': 'perpetual-protocol', 'coingecko_id': '', 'name': 'Perpetual Protocol', 'rank': 373, 'symbol': 'PERP', 'fullname': 'Perpetual Protocol (PERP)'}]
11                                                                    [{'id': 'new-paradigm-assets-solution', 'coingecko_id': '', 'name': 'New Paradigm Assets Solution', 'rank': 0, 'symbol': 'NPAS', 'fullname': 'New Paradigm Assets Solution (NPAS)'}]
12                                                                                                                                       [{'id': 'handy', 'coingecko_id': '', 'name': 'Handy', 'rank': 0, 'symbol': 'HANDY', 'fullname': 'Handy (HANDY)'}]
13        [{'id': 'fabwelt', 'coingecko_id': '', 'name': 'Fabwelt', 'rank': 2626, 'symbol': 'WELT', 'fullname': 'Fabwelt (WELT)'}, {'id': 'metarun', 'coingecko_id': '', 'name': 'Metarun', 'rank': 3092, 'symbol': 'MRUN', 'fullname': 'Metarun (MRUN)'}]
14                                                                                                                                     [{'id': 'dungeon', 'coingecko_id': '', 'name': 'Dungeon', 'rank': 0, 'symbol': 'DGN', 'fullname': 'Dungeon (DGN)'}]
15                                                                                                                                  [{'id': 'monetha', 'coingecko_id': '', 'name': 'Monetha', 'rank': 1967, 'symbol': 'MTH', 'fullname': 'Monetha (MTH)'}]

              date_event  can_occur_before          created_date  \
0   2022-07-13T00:00:00Z             False  2022-06-27T14:39:15Z
1   2022-07-13T00:00:00Z             False  2022-07-09T13:27:25Z
2   2022-07-13T00:00:00Z             False  2022-07-02T06:10:09Z
3   2022-07-13T00:00:00Z             False  2022-07-07T13:55:34Z
4   2022-07-13T00:00:00Z             False  2022-07-11T18:42:01Z
5   2022-07-13T00:00:00Z             False  2022-07-11T18:16:08Z
6   2022-07-13T00:00:00Z             False  2022-07-06T06:55:16Z
7   2022-07-13T00:00:00Z             False  2022-07-12T13:59:23Z
8   2022-07-13T00:00:00Z             False  2022-07-11T18:43:02Z
9   2022-07-13T00:00:00Z             False  2022-07-11T14:12:23Z
10  2022-07-13T00:00:00Z             False  2022-07-11T14:11:47Z
11  2022-07-13T00:00:00Z             False  2022-07-12T13:49:28Z
12  2022-07-13T00:00:00Z             False  2022-07-12T14:05:15Z
13  2022-07-13T00:00:00Z             False  2022-07-12T18:46:28Z
14  2022-07-13T00:00:00Z             False  2022-07-12T13:48:55Z
15  2022-07-13T00:00:00Z             False  2022-07-12T23:33:03Z

                                 categories  \
0         [{'id': 14, 'name': 'Fork/Swap'}]
1       [{'id': 16, 'name': 'Team Update'}]
2           [{'id': 4, 'name': 'Exchange'}]
3           [{'id': 4, 'name': 'Exchange'}]
4   [{'id': 17, 'name': 'Staking/Farming'}]
5           [{'id': 4, 'name': 'Exchange'}]
6              [{'id': 7, 'name': 'Other'}]
7                [{'id': 9, 'name': 'AMA'}]
8                [{'id': 9, 'name': 'AMA'}]
9           [{'id': 4, 'name': 'Exchange'}]
10      [{'id': 16, 'name': 'Team Update'}]
11          [{'id': 4, 'name': 'Exchange'}]
12          [{'id': 4, 'name': 'Exchange'}]
13               [{'id': 9, 'name': 'AMA'}]
14          [{'id': 4, 'name': 'Exchange'}]
15          [{'id': 4, 'name': 'Exchange'}]
```

1. I need to change the column "title": delete the key 'en' and stay only values.
2. I need to change the column "coins": extract keys as separate columns and put there their values.
3. I need to change the column "categories": delete the key "id" and values from "id", delete the key "name", but stay values from "name"

Comment: how do you create your dataframe ?

Comment: provide dataframe content as csv for example.

Comment: @Devyl ```def list_of_events(self):
     
        parameters = {"limit" : "10"}
        url = self.base_url + self.events
        pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None) 
        pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
    
        try:
            response = self.sessionInit().get(url, params = parameters)
            data = json.loads(response.text)
            df = pd.DataFrame(data["body"])
           
        except (ConnectionError, NameError) as e:
            print(e)
        print(df)
        return df```

Comment: @betagreen Where i can provide csv to you? Comments in stack overflow don't allow to put files or long text

Comment: you can edit your original post and add as plain text

Comment: can you provide the dict correpsonding to your data frame? You get that by the following command: `df.to_dict()` - [here is the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

Answer (score 0):

For columns with list in rows i would use pandas.explode

For columns with dict rows, use .apply(pandas.Series)

and then rename the columns with same name if u want use it (like 'id') or reformat the dicts when you get the parsed json

should look like this

```py
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({
    '1': [[{"id": 1, "a": 1}], [{"id": 2, "a": 1}]],
    '2': [1, 2],
    '3': [[{"id": 1, "name": "a"}], [{"id": 2, "name": "b"}]],
    '4': [{"en": "a"}, {"en": "b"}]
})
df = df.explode(["1", "3"])
pandas.concat([
    df.drop(["1", "3", "4"], axis=1),
    df['1'].apply(pandas.Series),
    df['3'].apply(pandas.Series),
    df['4'].apply(pandas.Series)
], axis=1)
```